# How would I use git and bash to recursively move all files in the a folder with the name `n` up one directory

Tags: bash, git

I am working on reorganizing an existing project. They had the following weird structure.

```
src
-main
--app
---item
----src
-----Item.coffee
---other
----src
-----Other.coffee
```

I want to move all these files in git so Item.coffee, etc is now under...

```
src
-main
--app
---item
----Item.coffee
---other
----Other.coffee
```

What is the proper Bash/Git command for this?

Answer (score 1):

How many files are you moving? Unless you are talking about dozens/hundreds/thousands of files, just physically move the file—by hand via GUI or via the `mv` command—to the new location and Git will detect the fact the file was:

1. Deleted from the old location.
2. Is a new file in the new location.

So to add the new files just do a `git add *` at the root of your project after the files are moved, do a commit and Git will handle the rest including noting that the file that was in one place is now in another.

And if somehow you *are* talking about dozens/hundreds/thousands of files then you would just need to script something in Bash to move the files and then do the same `git add *` and commit process and all should be good.

A Bash script like this should work to move all items ending in the `*.coffee` extension up one directory in the tree no matter how deeply nested it is:

```
find . -name '*.coffee' |\
  while read item_path
  do
    item_dirname=$(dirname "${item_path}");
    mv ${item_path} ${item_dirname}/..;
  done
```

PS: At no point should you ever be using `git rm` for a procedure like this. Just move the files, use `git add *` to add the newly moved files and then do a Git commit and all should be fine.

Comment: It is a lot of files so this is not going to work

Comment: Also I need to maintain the ability to merge up from master so removing and adding is a no go

Comment: I know but I tried to do a `git rm`, `mv` and then a `git add` and it saw it as a new file. Not exactly sure why